# Confidence regions of 1sigma for a 2D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, confidence-interval

I have two variables that I have plotted using `matplotlib` scatter function. [image]

**`I would like to show the 68% confidence region by highlighting it in the plot.`** I know to show it in a histogram, but I don't know how to do it for a 2D plot like this (x vs y). In my case, the `x is Mass` and `y is Ngal Mstar+2`.

**An example image of what I am looking for looks like this:**

Here they have showed the 68% confidence region using dark blue and 95% confidence region using light blue.

**Can it be achieved using one of the**`scipy.stats` modules?

[image]

Comment: If you have access to it, [seaborn](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html) has just what you want all fancy and built in - look up `regplot`.

Comment: @Ajean I believe you have shown me the thing I need! Let me try it out

Comment: I've used R packages in python to do this in the past, but I'm interested in an easier solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **thank you @snake_charmer** for your answer, **but I have found a simpler way of solving the issue using** `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize`

I fit my data sample using `curve_fit` which gives me my best fit parameters. What it also gives me is the estimated covariance of the parameters. The diagonals of the same provide the variance of the parameter estimate. To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters we can use `np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))` where `pcov` is the covariance matrix.

```
def fitfunc(M,p1,p2):
    N = p1+( (M)*p2 )
    return N
```

The above is the fit function I use for the data.

Now to fit the data using `curve_fit`

```
popt_1,pcov_1 = curve_fit(fitfunc,logx,logn,p0=(10.0,1.0),maxfev=2000)

p1_1 = popt_1[0]
p1_2 = popt_1[1]

sigma1 = [np.sqrt(pcov_1[0,0]),np.sqrt(pcov_1[1,1])] #THE 1 SIGMA CONFIDENCE INTERVALS
residuals1 = (logy) - fitfunc((logx),p1_1,p1_2)
xi_sq_1 = sum(residuals1**2) #THE CHI-SQUARE OF THE FIT

curve_y_1 = fitfunc((logx),p1_1,p1_2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(logx,logy,c='r',label='$0.0<z<0.5$')
ax1.plot(logx,curve_y_1,'y')
ax1.plot(logx,fitfunc(logx,p1_1+sigma1[0],p1_2+sigma1[1]),'m',label='68% conf limits')
ax1.plot(logx,fitfunc(logx,p1_1-sigma1[0],p1_2-sigma1[1]),'m')
```

**`So just by using the square root the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix, I can obtain the 1 sigma confidence lines.`**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To plot a region between two curves, you could use `pyplot.fill_between()`.

As for your confidence region, I was not sure what you wanted to achieve, so I exemplified with simultaneous confidence bands, by modifying the code from:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands#cite_note-2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.special as sp

## Sample size.
n = 50

## Predictor values.
XV = np.random.uniform(low=-4, high=4, size=n)
XV.sort()

## Design matrix.
X = np.ones((n,2))
X[:,1] = XV

## True coefficients.
beta = np.array([0, 1.], dtype=np.float64)

## True response values.
EY = np.dot(X, beta)

## Observed response values.
Y = EY + np.random.normal(size=n)*np.sqrt(20)

## Get the coefficient estimates.
u,s,vt = np.linalg.svd(X,0)
v = np.transpose(vt)
bhat = np.dot(v, np.dot(np.transpose(u), Y)/s)

## The fitted values.
Yhat = np.dot(X, bhat)

## The MSE and RMSE.
MSE = ((Y-EY)**2).sum()/(n-X.shape[1])
s = np.sqrt(MSE)

## These multipliers are used in constructing the intervals.
XtX = np.dot(np.transpose(X), X)
V = [np.dot(X[i,:], np.linalg.solve(XtX, X[i,:])) for i in range(n)]
V = np.array(V)

## The F quantile used in constructing the Scheffe interval.
QF = sp.fdtri(X.shape[1], n-X.shape[1], 0.95)
QF_2 = sp.fdtri(X.shape[1], n-X.shape[1], 0.68)

## The lower and upper bounds of the Scheffe band.
D = s*np.sqrt(X.shape[1]*QF*V)
LB,UB = Yhat-D,Yhat+D
D_2 = s*np.sqrt(X.shape[1]*QF_2*V)
LB_2,UB_2 = Yhat-D_2,Yhat+D_2


## Make the plot.
plt.clf()
plt.plot(XV, Y, 'o', ms=3, color='grey')
plt.hold(True)
a = plt.plot(XV, EY, '-', color='black', zorder = 4)

plt.fill_between(XV, LB_2, UB_2, where = UB_2 >= LB_2, facecolor='blue', alpha= 0.3, zorder = 0)
b = plt.plot(XV, LB_2, '-', color='blue', zorder=1)
plt.plot(XV, UB_2, '-', color='blue', zorder=1)

plt.fill_between(XV, LB, UB, where = UB >= LB, facecolor='blue', alpha= 0.3, zorder = 2)
b = plt.plot(XV, LB, '-', color='blue', zorder=3)
plt.plot(XV, UB, '-', color='blue', zorder=3)

d = plt.plot(XV, Yhat, '-', color='red',zorder=4)

plt.ylim([-8,8])
plt.xlim([-4,4])

plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:
[image]